# Looking for a solution: animate a custom view when item in RecyclerView is selected

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I don't have much experience in Android animation so I'm asking for some help for the following:

I have a RecyclerView and a custom view which appears whenever one of the items from RecyclerView is selected (gets binded with certain data etc.). 
What I need to make is an animation that would clearly show the new view 'fade in & rise'/ 'expand' from the location of that selected RecyclerView and spread through the whole screen.

For better visualisation : [force touch in certain iOS apps](http://www.howtoisolve.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/4-force-touch-for-mail-App.jpg) does this perfectly.

Are there any good 3rd party libraries for this sort of animations or any other solution? I tried working with built-in Android animations functions but I find them very limited for this kind of animations.

Comment: https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators please refer this library

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague: are you asking either how to create the 'force touch' animation either how pass the click event from your view holder to the main app?

Anyways, there's a library that does specifically what you want: [Android 3D Touch - PeekView](https://github.com/klinker24/Android-3DTouch-PeekView)